# Comic book short story about man trying to escape Hades

Tags: story-identification, comics, horror, supernatural

It is a story from a comic book that had to be published before 1967. I remember a splash page which shows, in a bird's eye view, a bespectacled man climbing a sheer, rocky cliff face with a trail of people climbing behind him. Below is a narrow, stark valley or gorge in which a crowd of people are standing in front of a massive and tall set of wooden doors. Apparently the gates of Hades.

The story may have been slight humorous. I think it ends with him getting pitch-forked in the behind. I have looked everywhere. In all the on-line public domain comics that would reasonably have such a story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! It's in [*Forbidden Worlds #129*](https://www.comics.org/issue/19336/) (ACG-1965). But not quite as I thought. The Stack Exchange Effect (I post; it's found) once more. And only 11 days.

[image: Front cover of Forbidden Worlds #129]

> An anthology series featuring tales of fantasy and science fiction adventure from legendary early independent comics publisher ACG. Magicman battles aliens who have taken over the bodies of a team of space explorers; A con artist offers to help Satan run the place after he arrives in Hell; The new member of a diving crew turns out to be an exceptionally good diver – too good to be entirely human. Well Bury You Deep!; Theres a New Lot of Spirits Coming In!; The Thing from the Depths

Comment: Nice! Don't forget to self-accept your answer, you can do so on your other question as well.

Comment: In case you're unfamiliar with how to accept, it's the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: And how did you find it?

Comment: I'm guessing it was "Theres a New Lot of Spirits Coming In!" just based off of titles?

Comment: I did a process of elimination on My Comic Shop's summaries since Comic Book Plus, or anyone else, had no complete set of Forbidden Worlds. Then ordered it on Amazon from Micheal's Golden Age comics. Excellent dealer.And it is "There's A New Lot Of Spirits Coming In" but what I thought the splash page was is just a simple medium-shot panel. You'd think something I saw 55 years ago at age five for thirty seconds would be better remembered. Aw, well.